# ProGuard on Flutter using 3rd party packages

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, proguard

Is it necessary to use proguard on your flutter app?

I'm trying to secure my app and the only one things I know is to handle the user data using `flutter_secure_storage`. I want a maximum security of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should understand what proguard is and what it can do.

Short description: it is a tool for code **shrinking**, **obfuscation**, and **optimization** in Android development. When you build a Flutter app for Android, you can use ProGuard to reduce the size of your app's APK and make it harder for **reverse-engineers** to understand your code.

For Security purpose other than data, you should keep this in mind.

1. **Use HTTPS**: Use HTTPS to encrypt data transmitted between your app
   and your server to prevent eavesdropping and data tampering.
2. **Implement encryption**: Use encryption algorithms such as AES or RSA
   to protect sensitive data, such as passwords or credit card details,
   stored on the device.
3. **Use authentication and authorization**: Implement user authentication
   and authorization mechanisms to prevent unauthorized access to your
   app's data and functionalities.
4. **Use code obfuscation**: Use code obfuscation tools like ProGuard or R8
   to make it harder for attackers to reverse-engineer your app's code.
5. **Implement secure coding practices**: Follow secure coding practices
   such as avoiding hardcoding sensitive data in the app's code,
   validating user inputs, and avoiding third-party libraries with
   known security vulnerabilities.

Implementing these measures can help you achieve maximum security for your Flutter app. However, keep in mind that security is a continuous process, and you should regularly review and update your security measures to keep up with evolving security threats.